# Attempt to write a function with cubed log runtime complexity $O(\log^3 n)$

Tags: time-complexity

I'm learning Data Structures and Algorithms now, I have a practical question that asked to write a function with O(log<sup>3</sup>n), which means log(n)*log(n)*log(n).

```
public void run(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2) {
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have come with this solution, but it seems not correct. Please help me out.

Comment: Is that all you have to do? Have you tried to compute log3n first and then have the program wait for the specified amount of time :)

Comment: Yeah. The simplest way for that would be to replace every `n` with `floor(log(n))`.

Comment: @phg Is my logic wrong? And if yes, could you please point out where is wrong

Comment: It is correct. 3 nested `for`s make a `^3`, and multiplying with 2 approaches n logarithmically. There's just a trivial way to "construct" a desired complexity `O(f(n))` by doing `for(int i=0; i<f(n); i++)`, as pointed out by usr.

Comment: You can also be pedantic and give binary search: $O(\dots)$ allows asymptotically *faster* algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is correct. Your could also iterate `Math.Log(n)*Math.Log(n)*Math.Log(n)` times. Not sure if that is considered cheating.

Comment: It is allowed, but our lecturer recommend us to write the function without using math library.

Answer (score 4):

The following trivially is in the complexity class $O(\log^3 n)$:

```
public void run (int n) {
    return;
}
```

But here is a solution with average and worst case of $O(\log^3 n)$:

```
// O(log(n)), n = |orderedVals|
int findClosest (int needle, int[] orderedVals) {
    // binary search for closest value and return it
}

// O(log(n)^3), n = |orderedVals|
int weirdSum (int initialNeedle, int[] orderedVals) {
    int sum = 0;
    int needle1 = initialNeedle;
    int needle2 = findClosest(needle1, vals);
    for (int i = 0; i < needle2; ++i) {
        int needle3 = findClosest(needle2, vals);
        for (int j = 0; i < needle3; ++j) {
            sum += findClosest(needle2, vals);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The first algorithm _also_ has an average and worst-case run-time of $O(\log^3 n)$.  Perhaps you meant $\Theta(\log^3 n)$?